# pandas groupby two variables, transform to list-of-list, and multiindexed df?

Tags: list, pandas, nested, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe that looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'ID'   : ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'],
  'date' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 
  'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
)
```

1) How can I create a list-of-list of `value` (presumably with a `groupby` query) so that I get the outer group grouped by `ID` and inner group by `date`:

- The expected result would look like this: `[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]`
- The query should be in pandas and ideally without for loops.

2) Add on question:
How could I get a multi-indexed dataframe from the groupby query:

For example 
`g = df.groupby('id')`
desired output:

```
id  date  value
A   1     1
    2     4
    3     7
B   1     2
    2     5
    3     8
C   1     3
    2     5
    3     9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [73]: df.groupby(['ID'])['value'].apply(list).tolist()
Out[73]: [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

answer for the add-on question:

```
In [110]: df.sort_values(['ID','date']).set_index(['ID','date'])
Out[110]:
         value
ID date
A  1         1
   2         4
   3         7
B  1         2
   2         5
   3         8
C  1         3
   2         6
   3         9
```

Comment: That's great. Is there also a way to show it as a multi indexed dataframe instead of a list of list? How could I convert the groupby objects into a multi indexed dataframe?

Comment: @Nickpick, it depends... Can you post your desired multi-index DF in your question?

Comment: added an add-on-question